# SQL utilizando multiplicação em nível

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá, estou enfrentando um problema para montar um SQL onde a quantidade do componente do produto filho seja multiplicado em nível pelo produto anterior.
Considerando a tabela abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE Produtos(
    [Cod] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [Produto] VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE ProdutosFormulacoes(
    [Cod] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CodProdutos] [int] NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE ProdutosFormulacoesComponentes(
    [Cod] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [CodProdutosFormulacoes] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CodProdutos] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CodComponentes] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Quantidade] [numeric](23, 10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Produtos (Cod, Produto) VALUES 
(1,'Veículo Finalizado'),
(2,'kit de Eixo'),
(3,'Kit de Rodas'),
(4,'Kit de Pneus'),
(5,'Ventil');

INSERT INTO ProdutosFormulacoes (Cod, CodProdutos) VALUES 
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,3),
(4,4);

INSERT INTO ProdutosFormulacoesComponentes(Cod, CodProdutosFormulacoes, CodProdutos, CodComponentes, Quantidade) VALUES
--Veículo
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 1, 2, 2),
(3, 1, 1, 3, 2),
(4, 1, 1, 4, 2),
--Eixo
(5, 2, 2, 2, 1),
(5, 2, 2, 3, 2),
--Rodas
(6, 3, 3, 3, 1),--
(7, 3, 3, 4, 2),
--Pneu
(8, 4, 4, 4, 1),
(9, 4, 4, 5, 2),
--Ventil
(10, 5, 5, 5 ,1);
```

Ao executarmos o seguinte SQL

```
SELECT 
    comp.CodProdutos, 
    comp.CodComponentes, 
    QuantidadeComponente = comp.Quantidade
FROM ProdutosFormulacoes form 
INNER JOIN ProdutosFormulacoesComponentes comp on form.Cod = comp.CodProdutosFormulacoes
```

podemos ver o retorno como uma tabela, onde existem os produtos e seus componentes.

```
| CodProdutos| CodComponentes|QuantidadeComponente|
| --------- -| --------------|--------------------|
|1           |              1|                   1|
|1           |              2|                   2|
|1           |              3|                   2|
|1           |              4|                   2|
|2           |              2|                   1|
|2           |              3|                   2|
|3           |              3|                   1|
|3           |              4|                   2|
|4           |              4|                   1|
|4           |              5|                   2|
```

Pegando como exemplo o produto 1:
Para produzir 1 unidade do produto 1, precisamos de 2 unidades do produto 2

Para produzir 2 unidade do produto 2, precisamos de 2 unidades do produto 3

Para produzir 2 unidade do produto 2, precisamos de 2 unidades do produto 4

Para produzir 1 unidade do produto 1, precisamos de 1 unidades do produto 5

A pergunta é: como multiplicar cada componente com base nos níveis anteriores?

Nesse contexto, é necessário multiplicar de trás pra frente, ou seja,  1 (Prod 5) * 2 (Prod 4) * 2 (prod 3) * 2 (Prod 2) * 1 (Prod 1) = 8

Para produzir 1 unidade do produto 1, são necessários 8 unidades do componente 5

```
| CodProdutos| CodComponentes|QuantidadeComponente|**QuantidadeAjustada**
| --------- -| --------------|--------------------|------------------
|1           |              1|                   1|                 1
|1           |              2|                   2|                 2 
|1           |              3|                   2|                 2
|1           |              4|                   2|                 2

|2           |              2|                   1|                 2
|2           |              3|                   2|                 4

|3           |              3|                   1|                 2
|3           |              4|                   2|                 8

|4           |              4|                   1|                 4
|4           |              5|                   1|                 8
```

link para o SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3524dd/1/0

Comment: vc pode confirmar a quantidade de componentes 5 utilizados no componente 4? a quantidade total de componentes 5 para o produto 1 é 8 mesmo?

Comment: A quantidade de componentes do produto 5 para o produto 4 é uma unidade. 
Tens razão quanto à quantidade dinal do produto 5. O erro na tabela acima é que: para produzir o produto 3 (kit de rodas) preciso de apenas 1 kit pneu cada, e não 2 para cada kit roda. Com isso, a quantidade final ficaria 4 unidades do produto 5.
A síntese é a seguinte:
Para produzir 1 carro preciso de:
2 kit eixo,
4 Kit Roda,
4 Kit Pneu,
4 Ventil.

O problema é: e se eu quiser produzir 3 unidades, quanto eu preciso de cada componente com base na escala?

Comment: Acho que as linhas da tabela ProdutosFormulacoesComponentes não estão de acordo com a síntese que você postou acima. Primeiro porque o kit rodas e o kit pneus são componentes diretos do veículo e indiretos também (o kit pneus é componente do kit rodas que é componente do eixo), já o ventil me parece correto, é apenas componente indireto do kit pneus. E me parece que a quantidade de pneus por roda também não está correta. Melhor você confirmar esses dados

Comment: Independente de o produto ser componente direto ou indireto do produto pai, as quantidades finais deles devem ser multiplicadas pelas quantidades de níveis anteriores. Utilizando um exemplo real, na base de dados possuo um componente que é componente de outros 3 produtos distintos em níveis diferentes. Por exemplo, kit de parafuso, esse kit pode ser componente de vários produtos em vários níveis diferentes.

Comment: Coloquei essas questões em relação ao seu exemplo porque da forma como está acredito que o resultado seria diferente, mas voltando a questão, acredito que você consiga obter o resultado esperado utilizando uma CTE recursiva para obter os componentes e os subcomponentes sucessivamente e no final somar as quantidades de cada um

Comment: Sim, entendo sua dúvida, por isso expliquei o motivo das quantidades estarem diferentes. Com base na sua idéia, como montaríamos esse CTE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão de CTE recursiva para testes considerando o exemplo que você postou no seu primeiro comentário dentro da pergunta:

```
DECLARE @Produtos TABLE (
    [Cod] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [Produto] VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @ProdutosFormulacoes TABLE (
    [Cod] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CodProdutos] [int] NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @ProdutosFormulacoesComponentes TABLE (
    [Cod] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [CodProdutosFormulacoes] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CodProdutos] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CodComponentes] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Quantidade] [numeric](23, 10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Produtos 
(Cod, Produto) VALUES 
(1,'Veículo Finalizado'),
(2,'kit de Eixo'),
(3,'Kit de Rodas'),
(4,'Kit de Pneus'),
(5,'Ventil');

INSERT INTO @ProdutosFormulacoes 
(Cod, CodProdutos) VALUES 
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,3),
(4,4);

INSERT INTO @ProdutosFormulacoesComponentes 
(Cod, CodProdutosFormulacoes, CodProdutos, CodComponentes, Quantidade) VALUES
--Veículo
(2, 1, 1, 2, 2),
--Eixo
(5, 2, 2, 3, 2),
--Rodas
(7, 3, 3, 4, 1),
--Pneu
(9, 4, 4, 5, 1);

WITH CTE_REC AS
(
    SELECT 
        form.CodProdutos as CodPrincipal,
        comp.CodProdutos, 
        comp.CodComponentes, 
        QuantidadeComponente = comp.Quantidade
    FROM @ProdutosFormulacoes form 
    INNER JOIN @ProdutosFormulacoesComponentes comp 
        on form.Cod = comp.CodProdutosFormulacoes 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        r.CodPrincipal,
        comp.CodProdutos, 
        comp.CodComponentes, 
        cast(comp.Quantidade * r.QuantidadeComponente as numeric(23, 10))
    FROM CTE_REC r
    INNER JOIN @ProdutosFormulacoes form 
        on r.CodComponentes = form.CodProdutos
    INNER JOIN @ProdutosFormulacoesComponentes comp 
        on form.Cod = comp.CodProdutosFormulacoes 
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_REC
ORDER BY CodPrincipal
```

Observações:

- a quantidade de "Ventil" do "Kit pneu" foi alterada para 1 e a de "Kit pneu" do "Kit roda" alterada para 1 também.
- o "Kit roda" e o "Kit pneu" não estão como componentes diretos do "Veículo", apenas como componentes indiretos
- os produtos não estão como componentes deles mesmos
- o SQLFiddle estava instável no momento dos testes

Comment: Perfeito. Adequado ao meu modelo. Problema resolvido. Muito grato pela ajuda!!!